# The opposite of "discontinued"?

Tags: word-choice

When a product is no longer produced it's said to be "discontinued", but what's the opposite? "Continued" doesn't seem right to my ears, but maybe it is?

I considered "Available" but it doesn't work because a product could be unavailable yet not discontinued. I'm thinking of plumping for "Active" unless someone knows a better word?

Comment: What's wrong with available if there are 3 possible states: Available, Unavailable and Discontinued ?

Comment: In my situation, availability is a lot more complicated than that - it depends on e.g. locale, and stock. A product might be available in one locale and unavailable in another, and may also have been discontinued yet still remain in stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring strictly to products then "in production" would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Actually I want a short word (it's a database column) so I'll call it "produced"... funny that word was in my question and I didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by opposite, but I think the word you're looking for is:

> [recontinue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recontinue) - to continue again

Answer (score 0):

I use the term "reintroduced", when referring to products. "Relaunch" was also suggested to me at one time.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please add references to support your answer.